# How to load html string by use WKWebView

Tags: ios8, wkwebview

How to load html string by use WKWebView.

I just found `loadRequest` method. The only way I can think of is to save the html string to file, and load it by `NSURLRequest` .......

Comment: Please specify exactly what you want to do and add some code of what you've already tried.

Answer (score 3):

In beta 3 i found this in WKWebView

```
 /*! @abstract Sets the webpage contents and base URL.
     @param string The string to use as the contents of the webpage.
     @param baseURL A URL that is used to resolve relative URLs within the document.
     @result A new navigation.
     */
    func loadHTMLString(string: String!, baseURL: NSURL!) -> WKNavigation!
```

So you can load html string just as you did with UIWebView